# Bourne Shell Building and referencing a variable

Tags: shell, sh

I have a shell that runs where the preset env variables include:

```
FOOCOUNT=4
FOO_0=John
FOO_1=Barry
FOO_2=Lenny
FOO_3=Samuel
```

I can not change the way I get this data.

I want to run a loop that generates up the variable and uses the contents.

```
echo "Hello $FOO_count"
```

This syntax is however wrong and that is what I am searching for...

```
count=$FOOCOUNT
counter=0
while [ $counter -lt $count ]
do
#I am looking for the syntax for: <<myContructedVar= $ + 'FOO_' + $counter>>
counter=`expr $counter + 1`
echo "Greeting #$counter: Hello, ${myContructedVar}."
done
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is `eval`:

```
count=$FOOCOUNT
counter=0
while [ $counter -lt $count ]
do
    myConstructedVar=FOO_$counter
    counter=`expr $counter + 1`
    echo "Greeting #$counter: Hello, `eval echo \$${myConstructedVar}`."
done
```

The loop arithmetic is old school - the way I write the code.  Modern shells have more arithmetic built in - but the question is tagged Bourne shell.

Comment: This is perfect. I wasn't familiar with eval but eval myVar=\$${myConstructedVar} worked perfectly.Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need an `eval` and a deferred sigil:

```
$ foo_0=john
$ count=0    
$ name="\$foo_$count"
$ echo $name
$foo_0
$ eval echo "$name"    
john
```

but unless the index is truly important to you, you might use

```
for i in "$foo_0" "$foo_1" "$foo_2" ... ; do
...
done
```

and get rid of the badly named pseudo-array. And, if you have an upper bound on the number of the number of `foo_x` *and* there are no special characters in the various foos (in particular no character in `$IFS` which defaults to `<space><tab><return>`) then you can use the null-argument collapsing feature of the shell and:

```
$ for i in $foo_0 $foo_1 $foo_2 ; do
> echo '***' $i
> done
*** john
```

and allow the shell to ignore unset `foo_x`

Answer (score 0):

It's been a very long time since I've done any Bourne shell but have you tried the eval command?